# How to dynamically populate a dropdown

Tags: menus, navigation

I am tasked with creating a subnav in the body of our custom-built pages. The nav's last item is supposed to be a clickable dropdown (a "more" button) that can dynamically populate if extra pages are added via the dashboard. I'm trying to figure out how to code this in PHP and JS without a plug-in. Any sort of point in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my best shot, although when I add another item to the dropdown, the styling gets weird. https://codepen.io/bfoley650/pen/PoZwKeb